# Using Func<var,var> to make Func<var>

Tags: c#, function

I have to functions one that returns a string Function1: `Func<string>` and another that has string input and returns a string Function2 `Func<string, string>`.

What I'd like to do is be able to call the inputs from the second function and cast it as Func1 with only a return.

Attempt1:
`Func1<string> function = Function2("Foo")`
Returns

> Can't convert string to Func<string>

Comment: `Function2("Foo")` returns some `string` result, which is not `Func<string>`.  `Func1<string> function = () => Function2("Foo");`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Inline solution

`Func1<string> function = () => Function2("Foo");`

End Edit

Made a method that solves this problem.

```
public Func<string> CastFunction( Func<string, string> FunctionInput, string input1) 
{           
Func<string> FunctionReturn = () => FunctionInput(input1);

return FunctionReturn; 
}
```

Comment: What you are doing has a name, by the way: [Partial Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). It is closely related to currying.

Comment: Is creating this method really more readable than doing it inline?  i.e. `Func1<string> function = () => Function2("Foo");`

Comment: @KirkWoll No, that should be the answer.